# SQL Server UDF to Reverse Arabic Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to develop a UDF to reverse Arabic characters and keep the English as they are .. I developed it but It returned null .. Please assist

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StripVenNameAR] (@InString as NVarChar(4000))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000) AS
BEGIN
  Declare @ReturnVal as smallint
  Declare @OutString as NVarchar(4000)
  Declare @Pos as smallint
  Declare @CurChar as NVarChar(1)
  Declare @NEWChar as NVarChar(1)

SET @ReturnVal = 0

IF LEN(@InString) = 0                      
    SET @ReturnVal = 0                
ELSE                       

BEGIN                      
    Set @Pos = 1                   
    SET @OutString = ' '                   
    WHILE (@Pos <= Len(@InString))                 
     BEGIN                  

        Set @CurChar =  SUBSTRING(@InString, @Pos, 1)              

        IF unicode(@CurChar) between 1536 and 1791


         SET  @NEWChar = REVERSE(@CurChar)

            SET @ReturnVal = @Pos

            Set @Pos = @Pos + 1

       SET @OutString = @OutString  +  @NEWChar      

    END 

    END

    RETURN @OutString

END
```

Comment: Revere a single character at a time does nothing. The reverse of a a single character is that single character.  But I still don't know why that returns null.

Comment: Hello Blam .. it causes because of space I guess, it reads it as a null value .. all I need now .. how to concatenate null with characters to build the string again.

Answer (score 0):

For non-arabic characters, @NEWChar is NULL.  When you combine NULL with @OutString, the result is NULL.  While I don't know precisely what you are going for, here is a version of the function that works for English characters and appears to me to do what you are looking for.

Edit: I altered the function to do what you were looking for.  In order to accomplish that, you have to treat each section of text as a block and identify that block as Arabic or non-Arabic.  At the end of each block, we append the reversed block output if the block was Arabic and append the straight block output if the block was non-Arabic.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].StripVenNameAR (@InString AS NVARCHAR(4000)) 
returns NVARCHAR(4000) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @OutString AS NVARCHAR(4000) 
      DECLARE @Pos AS SMALLINT 
      DECLARE @CurChar AS NVARCHAR(1) 
      DECLARE @Mode AS NVARCHAR(2) 
      DECLARE @PrevMode AS NVARCHAR(2) 
      DECLARE @PartialString AS NVARCHAR(4000) 

      SET @Mode = 'EN' 
      SET @PrevMode = 'EN' 
      SET @Pos = 1 
      SET @OutString = ' ' 
      SET @PartialString = '' 

      WHILE ( @Pos <= Len(@InString) ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @CurChar = Substring(@InString, @Pos, 1) 
            SET @Mode = CASE 
                          WHEN Unicode(@CurChar) BETWEEN 1536 AND 1791 THEN 'AR'
                           ELSE 'EN' 
                        END 

            IF ( @PrevMode <> @Mode ) 
              BEGIN 
                  IF ( @PrevMode = 'AR' ) 
                    SET @OutString = @OutString + Reverse(@PartialString) 
                  ELSE 
                    SET @OutString = @OutString + @PartialString 

                  SET @PartialString = '' 
              END 

            SET @Pos = @Pos + 1 
            SET @PartialString = @PartialString + @CurChar 
            SET @PrevMode = @Mode 
        END 

      IF ( @PrevMode = 'AR' ) 
        SELECT @OutString = @OutString + Reverse(@PartialString) 
      ELSE 
        SELECT @OutString = @OutString + @PartialString 

      RETURN @OutString 
  END
```

Comment: Hello Grax, .. I just need to function to check if the character is Arabic to reverse and If not keep it as it is .. as I have a column in database contains mix of arabic and english characters like ' Name مسا' i just need the function to make it ' Name اسم' .. please advise

Comment: I edited the code sample to parse blocks, identify them as Arabic or non-Arabic, and reverse the block if Arabic.

Comment: Hello Grace, Thanks for your support but your functions works fine when I pass a static parameter to it like select [dbo].StripVenNameAR('Name مسا') but when I call it in select statement like select [dbo].StripVenNameAR(CompanyName) from Companies... it doesn't reverse anything .. please advise

Comment: I don't know. It should work as long as company name is an nvarchar in the dataw

Comment: It does work for me.  Here is the test I used. create table nametest(
  Id int identity primary key,
  name nvarchar(255)
 )

 insert into nametest
 values (N' Name مسا')

 select name, dbo.StripVenNameAR(name) from nametest